"Modified [date]" should not be hyperlinked
We read

Should clicking the "Modified today" [or in fact any day] link show me something? The
question seems to reload, but no new information is displayed.

That's because it links to "(Same URL)?lastactivity".
Which just reloads the page, confusing users. And thus such a bogus hyperlink is definitely a mis-feature that needs to be removed, leaving just the text words, but no hyperlink.
"Modified [date]" should not be hyperlinked
"Modified [date]" should not be hyperlinked in the case when clicking it will do nothing

"Which just reloads the page, confusing users." it goes to the post on the page that had the last activity. That might be the question, but in other cases might be an answer. It's not just reloading the page. The only real flaw with that functionality is that it's somewhat hidden and the hyperlink is not evident.

Well all I know is in 53% of the situations, it does exactly nothing other than reloading the same page, confusing users.

There's definitely UX problem here, but removing features is not the way to fix it.

Are you specifically looking at the most recently active posts? Because it is a lot more useful at that point when some Q&A from years ago gets some activity today and you want to find out what that activity was. If you're just looking at the recent questions, then I'd agree that activity is not very useful. I'd advise just not clicking the link, though. I don't use the elevator in my block because it doesn't go to my floor. I'd rather not say it should be removed because it is of no use to me.

The problem is there is no sign on the elevator that it only stops on even floors, so you only know once you ... went through the trouble of pushing the button, which oddly did not light up, and nothing happened, which is about the same case with our computer story here.

I am not specifically looking for anything. All I know is in this lifetime I have pushed it several times and nothing happened. Perhaps others, who look for other posts, than the ones I looked for, have the opposite experience.

This is a useful feature for those in the know: It highlights the post on the page with the last activity. While this isn't usually particularly useful when the question was the last active, it is useful for finding new or edited answers when there are a lot.
I have no attachment to the current arcane UI design, but until there's a better (clearer) alternative on the page to do this, it should stay.

All I know is that I am one of the unlucky, who have never experienced the other situations you describe, so it is therefore broken for me.

"It highlights" = "It briefly highlights and scrolls to". Hum, actually rather "It scrolls to and briefly highlights".

@DanJacobson that's such a bizarrely self-centered response - saying its "broken for me" just because you haven't encountered the case that it is intended to work. "Bad UI" I would agree, but not "broken" - unless you are suggesting that it fails to work even in cases that Laurel's answer says it should? If so, do you have an example?

UX problems, as others mentioned.

This is really useful to know; I've started using it already. Do you know if there's a Meta post anywhere else about it? If not, I'm almost tempted to start a dedicated Q&A so we can properly document the behavior.

Laurel's answer pretty completely explains why this feature is good. I think it's also worth noting that it isn't bad.
You wanted to remove it because the hyperlink "just reloads the page, confusing users." But honestly, I don't see that as a problem. The link doesn't break the site or remove any functionality. Plus, it's pretty unobtrusive, so it's not creating any mental load.

UX problems, as others mentioned.

@DanJacobson The existence of a problem is not the same as the severity of a problem. Even if the link is unintuitive, what harm is it really causing? Making people confused for a bit before they shrug their shoulders and move on? We have to compare the benefits to the drawbacks here; the downsides to these feature are minimal enough that some benefit to a few people is enough to justify keeping it.

How about enhancing it so that it confuses nobody?


"Modified [date]" should not be hyperlinked in the case when clicking it will do nothing

There's never a case where clicking it will "do nothing".
You likely mean cases where clicking it appears to just reload the page and not jump to a specific answer, which is a completely separate matter.
If nothing truly happened, then yes it would be a pointless hyperlink, but something does happen, it's just not always inherently clear what, according to you. So this should be a request to clarify the behavior, not remove the feature; your concern can be completely addressed by modifying the tooltip that appears on hover of the link to say something like:

Jumps to the specific post, including the question itself, with the most recent activity ([datetime]) on this page.

I recommend you post a separate feature-request here on Meta asking for the UX to be improved, instead... it's unlikely this question will be salvaged by an edit to that effect, at this point.
Relevant reading for this problem: The principle of Chesterton's fence.

As you certainly have a clearer vision for what needs to be done, could you please post the new proposal. Then I will add one comment: also be sure there is a message that comes up when the user clicks and "nothing apparently happens". That message should be just like when one wants to add a sixth tag, (saying that they have already reached the max), saying that they are already looking at the latest activity. Thanks! (Do add a link here to your new proposal. Thanks.)
